# Excel XLookup with queried SQL data on another sheet

Tags: sql, excel, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a purchase order in excel that pulls information from an Azure SQL Database.

I have performed a query and downloaded the data from the SQL database to another sheet.  I want the user to punch in a PO# and then have the data fields automatically fill out with the relevant information.

I am trying to use Xlookup to pull this information out of the data sheet but I am getting an error.

Where have I gone wrong here?

=XLOOKUP(E3,TBL_P_Purchasing!D2:D1001,TBL_P_Purchasing!B2:B1001,"error")

[image: Data]

[image: Data]

Comment: Looks like the PO# in the second screenshot might be formatted as text rather than a number.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the PO# data type. PO# is formatted as text but it should be integer.

Please change it and this should work fine.